# Pegar o valor do input com jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou tentando pegar o valor do  porém, ele me retorna apenas o input.pgt como pode ser visto na imagem acima, já tentei com .value e .val(), porém continua não funcionando, segue a imagem do código abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu preciso que ele retorne o valor que esteja no campo, ao invés de ele me retornar o valor que o usuário escreveu, ele me retorna o elemento do DOM, por exemplo: Eu digitei, "Masculino", "Feminino", em cada um dos campos que contém a classe "pgt", eu quero que esses dois valores aparecem no array opcoes (o qual está presente na imagem do console do chrome), mas ao invés de aparecer "Masculino", "Feminino", ele aparece "input.pgt", "input.pgt"

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não ficou claro o que deseja fazer Leonardo, pode nos fornecer um exemplo verificavel?

Comment: Acabei de editar a pergunta, verifique se está mais legível agora, por favor.

Comment: Coloque sempre o código como texto e formatado com o botão `{}`

Answer (score -1):

Consegui resolver o problema, o problema era que quando eu usava o `.get()` no final do `$.each`, ele pegar o elemento do DOM ao invés do valor, então resolvi usar o `.map()` no lugar do `.each()`, sendo assim, ele mapeia e me retorna o valor. Segue abaixo o código corrigido.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]